# Using Android phone to locate Zigbee sensor

Tags: android, bluetooth, rfid, zigbee

I'd like to tag something important with a ZigBee sensor and be able to know/track its approximate distance (ideally location, but I understand that would take many reference sensors) through my Android cell phone and alert me if it moves out of range.  Alternatively, use the cell from to locate RFID tags (I know the exact location isn't possible, but looking for +/- 5-10M).

Comment: Your android phone porbably doesn't have a zigbee radio or RFID reader, so you're going to need another device in your system.

Answer (score 0):

[rfid+zigbee used for location monitoring](http://www.libelium.com/rfid_nfc_zigbee_sensors/)

First and the for most thing that has to happen is that, android phone has to support zigbee. [This](http://www.cepro.com/article/taztag_claims_first_android_phone_with_nfc_zigbee/.) link shows a zigbee enabled android phone.

Another link: [zigbee enabled android phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4DrT.jpg)

The most important aspect of your question is that, the smartphone should act as a end device (node) in a zigbee network. Then if node ( smartphone ) moves out of zigbee network then it will be sensed by co-ordinator .

Answer (score 0):

I've been testing these SDIO ZigBee cards for a while:
http://www.spectec.com.tw/sdz-539.html
Although I haven't still managed to make them work in Android. But to be honest I've pushed the project aside for the last months :-(

Hope it helps. I would appreciate it if you could drop me a line if you find a solution or manage to use these devices.

Comment: Hi! I was wondering if you managed to get your zigbee sdio working on android? I need to enable zigbee on android but I am hesitating between usb otg and sdio solutions.

Comment: Hi, I did, though only with the sample apps, I'm still working in other project parts so this is still waiting for customization. It looks good though. I would recommend it over USB OTG solutions as the result is much more integrated & compact